# How to output names and line numbers with invalid expressions?

Tags: java, file

I need to check line in file (for some chars) and display files and lines with error in format

```
Uncorrect expressions:
 note1.txt line 2
 note2.txt line 5
```

My wrong code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        File input = new File(args[i]); // convert args to files

        String resultStrings = ConvertToString(input);  // converted to String lines

        for (int k = 0; k < resultStrings.length(); k++) {
            boolean isValid = CheckValid(resultStrings); //true - if necessary char compared, false if not

            if (isValid) {
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Uncorrect expressions:" + "\n");
                System.out.println(%wrongfilename% + "line" + %wrongline%);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How to get and output wrong file name and wrong line number ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this - integer expressions like (k + 1) are automatically converted to strings. Note that (k + 1) will match the user's expectation, as humans count from 1 rather than from 0.

```
System.out.println("Incorrect expressions:\n");
System.out.println(" " + args[i] + " line " + (k + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.err.println("Incorrect expressions:");    
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    String resultStrings = ConvertToString(new File(args[i]));
    for (int k = 0; k < resultStrings.length(); k++)
        if (!CheckValid(resultStrings))
            System.out.println(args[i] + "\tline " + (k+1));
}
```

I assume that you only want to print "Incorrect Expressions" *once* at the top, and not every time you find an incorrect line. Also, this will put tabs between the filename and line number, although you can simply replace the `"\t"` with a `" "` if you want.

Comment: Hi @Jashaszun, you can't take index of String (not String array) like this _resultStrings[k]_

Comment: @Mishel Oh oops, I was thinking in C#, not java. Edited.

Comment: @Mishel What is the error message, if there is one, and where is it located? I'd like to know what's wrong with my code so that I can fix it for you.

Comment: @Mishel Oh wow, I'm dumb... I thought that `resultStrings` was a `String[]`, not a `String`. Let me fix my answer, sorry.

Comment: @Mishel Also, your code (and even mine) won't work very well right now, because your `CheckValid` function takes the entire file as an argument, and not single lines at a time. So right now, it checks the *entire* file `n` times (where `n` is the number of characters in the file) and then simply prints out the error message either `n` or 0 times.